# Sql Server query not working as a subquery

Tags: sql-server-2008

Why is this query not working?

```
Select temp.CompanyName from

(
    SELECT  c.CompanyName, o.OrderID, 
            YEAR(o.OrderDate)  As YEAR, 
            Sum(od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) from Orders o 
        INNER JOIN [Order Details] od 
            ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
        INNER JOIN Customers c
            On c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
                GROUP BY o.OrderId,c.CompanyName, YEAR(o.OrderDate)

) As temp;
```

It uses Northwind database. If I run it without creating a temporary view i.e if I run the query just contained within round brackets it runs just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

at the first look i'd say because your Sum() doesn't have a column alias

Comment: Very Nice. You are right. But what problem could be caused just by not using column alias? If i run it without creating views it runs just fine.

Comment: First off, this is called a subquery, not a view.  Second, ask yourself how you could refer to a column without a name in the parent query, and I think you'll understand why this is an error.

Comment: Oh Thanks i thought this is view, since we are select something and then selecting again from 'something'.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
Select CompanyName from
(
    SELECT  c.CompanyName, o.OrderID, 
            YEAR(o.OrderDate)  As YEAR, 
            Sum(od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) as price from Orders o 
        INNER JOIN [Order Details] od 
            ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
        INNER JOIN Customers c
            On c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
                GROUP BY o.OrderId,c.CompanyName, YEAR(o.OrderDate)

)  temp
```